# How fo I filter by number of respondent in a particular place? Error:Error in FUN(left, right):

Tags: r, syntax-error

I want to be able to calculate % content by districts. The thing is, my data set is a survey where each row is a respondent.The number of row will increase as the number of respondents increases.

I want to be able to calculate the total number of respondents for each district as well as the total respondents who are content in each district.

I know I have to use a filter function somehow, but I am having trouble customizing it to what I want it to do in my case.

Here is my code:

```
jbnew <- jb %>%
   mutate(content = ifelse(as.numeric(sum.contentcir >= 3),1,0))%>%
   filter (jb, n())%>%
group_by(jb,district) %>%
   summarise(Num.Totalrespondents =n(),
             Num.totalcontent = sum(content))%>%
   mutate(percent.totalcontent = Num.totalcontent/Num.Totalrespondents)
```

the error i get this:

```
Error in FUN(left, right) : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

An example of my data:

```
    Districts    sum.contentcir  content
1     AMA              4             1
2     Dule             2             0
3     Dule             5             1
4     Dule             1             0
5     Sep              3             1
6     Sep              1             0
7     AMA              0             0
8     Sep              7             1
9     AMA              1             0
10    Sep              0             0
```

What I want my final dataset to look like:

```
Districts    Totalrespondents      totalcontent         per.content

AMA                3                    1                    33
Dule               3                    1                    33
Sep                4                    2                    50
```

The whole concept on what I need to do makes sense in my head, but I am having trouble translating it in a code. I'll appreciate your input on how this error is happening.

Comment: By using `filter (jb, n())` what are you trying to do?

Comment: I saw somewhere that you can use n() within filters, so I tried it. I was hoping it count every row in dataframe so that it can later group it by district. I want to know the total number of respondents for each district.

Comment: `filter` is used to remove rows using some logical condition.  Which rows do you want to remove? Can you add a reproducible example along with expected output?

Comment: I actually don't want to remove any rows. I didn't know filter was to remove rows. I want to keep all my rows, I just want to be able to count number of rows.I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, you can do :

```
library(dplyr)

jb %>%
  group_by(Districts) %>%
  summarise(Totalrespondents  = n(), 
            totalcontent = sum(content), 
            per.content = totalcontent/Totalrespondents * 100)

#  Districts Totalrespondents totalcontent per.content
#  <chr>                <int>        <int>       <dbl>
#1 AMA                      3            1        33.3
#2 Dule                     3            1        33.3
#3 Sep                      4            2        50
```

---

Same way using `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)

setDT(jb)[, .(Totalrespondents = .N,
              totalcontent = sum(content),
              per.content = sum(content)/.N * 100), Districts]
```